# CNAME SSL Redirect Setup with Cloudflare

Tags: https, cname-record, lets-encrypt, cloudflare, ssl-certificate-errors

I’m hosting two subdomains with two (non-wildcard) Let’s Encrypt certificates outside of cloudflare:
name.feed.example.com
name.example.com

I have a CNAME alias on Cloudflare (free plan) pointing
from name.example.com
to name.feed.example.com

I’m getting an Error 526: Invalid SSL certificate

Any ideas? Thank you! :*

Comment: Here's an article that has some background on what causes Cloudflare to give that error: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-526-invalid-ssl-certificates/44273  (I get the impression that you must be using the Cloudflare CDN for those domain names, are the LE certs you speak of used for secure connections between the CDN servers and the origin servers specifically, or how are those certs used?)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction